# Menú de opciones en app Android

Tags: android, menú

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación en Android Studio, y necesito que el Menú de opciones me aparezca en la parte inferior derecha de la pantalla, como se muestra en la Figura....
Alguien me puedar dar una ayuda en este tema????

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Dennis Vinicio Chicaiza Castil, bienvenido a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: Bienvenido te sugiero leer [ask] para que tus preguntas sean mejor recibidas en la comunidad, para lo que pides te recomiendo leer sobre el BottomNavigationView modifica tu pregunta, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

`BottomNavigationView` crea barras de navegación inferiores , lo que facilita explorar y cambiar entre vistas de contenido de nivel superior con un solo toque.

Este patrón se puede usar cuando tiene entre 3 y 5 destinos de nivel superior para navegar.

1. Cree un recurso de menú con hasta 5 objetivos de navegación ( BottomNavigationViewno admite más de 5 elementos).
2. Diseña BottomNavigationViewtu contenido debajo de ti.
3. Establezca el app:menuatributo en su BottomNavigationViewrecurso de menú.
4. Escuche los eventos de selección usando setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(...).

Un archivo de diseño típico se vería así:

```
 <FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <!-- Main content -->

  <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
      android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom"
      android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
      app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
      app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
      app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Ejemplo Visual

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Te dejo la Clase de la documentacion Oficial 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta... Parece que me expresé mal... La idea es que aparezca el botón de acceso al menú en la parte inferior derecha y al presionar dicho botón aparezcan las opciones que se han creado para dicho menú.....

Comment: Lo que pones como foto de muestra , no conicide con lo que pedis aca , por favor edita y se mas especifico

Answer (score 0):

`NavigationView` es una manera fácil de mostrar un menú de navegación.

`NavigationViewes` una vista desplazable que representa un recurso de menú ( R.menu.) como una lista vertical. También muestra una vista de encabezado sobre el menú.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
  android:id="@+id/navigation"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_gravity="start|left"
  app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
  app:menu="@menu/my_navigation_items" />
```

Banderas disponibles

`app:menu` apunta a un recurso de menú que se representará por `NavigationView`
`app:headerLayout` señala un recurso de diseño para usar como un encabezado para `NavigationView`

Manejo de selección

Puede usar `setNavigationItemSelectedListenerpara` escuchar la selección de elementos e implementar su lógica de navegación.